# Why does minus sign disappear when loading unicode-math and semantic packages?

Tags: xetex, unicode-math

is there any conflict between these two packages (unicode-math and semantic)? See for instance this MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{semantic}
\begin{document}
Test $a+b$ and $a-b$.
\end{document}
```

which produces (with xelatex):

[image]

If I remove any of the two packages, the minus sign is displayed correctly. Any suggestion or hack to fix this? I didn't notice problems with other glyphs.

Comment: Load `unicode-math` last?

Comment: I'm afraid that compatibility with `unicode-math` requires extensive changes in `ligature.sty` (a subpackage loaded by `semantic`). Also `|` and `*` are affected.

Comment: So it depends if the `ligature` feature is used!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested with `xelatex` but with `lualatex`, with the same error. I don't know why the error occurs but an easy fix is to change the loading order:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{semantic}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
    Test $a+b$ and $a-b$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This defeats the ligaturing mechanism set up by `semantic`.

Comment: Sorry I had trouble identifying exactly which packages were causing the problem, I should have tried that! Thank you for the fix, I'm using the semantic package only for the inference rules, and I don't really need the ligatures, so it is actually a convenient solution (at least for me).

Comment: Thus you can only load `\usepackage[inference]{semantic}`